# Not all tags returned in findAll using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm really stumped on this one. I want to return all the rows in the Recent Trades table at the following URL http://www.lse.co.uk/ShareTrades.asp?shareprice=IQE&share=iqe, however only 16 rows are ever returned from the `findAll`.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.lse.co.uk/ShareTrades.asp?shareprice=IQE&share=iqe').read())
tradesdate = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"TradesDate"})
tradestime = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"TradesTime"})
i = len(tradesdate)
for counter in range (0,i-1):
    print tradesdate[counter].string + " | " + tradestime[counter].string
    i += 1
```

Comment: There are only 16 rows in the website. You're probably authenticated.

Comment: You could try using the `requests` class to authenticate really simply then you will get the full response you see when logged in.

Comment: I thought it would be something stupid like that. Is there a way to authenticate via Python outside of the browser?

Comment: Brilliant, looks like requests is the way to go! Thank you for all your help.